# The process cannot access the file[VB.Net]

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save a file, then crypt is and delete the temporary uncrypted file. This is my encryption sub, the error line occurs on the last line.

```
Sub EncryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, _
              ByVal sOutputFilename As String, _
              ByVal sKey As String)

    Dim fsInput As New FileStream(sInputFilename, _
                                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim fsEncrypted As New FileStream(sOutputFilename, _
                                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

    'Set secret key for DES algorithm.
    'A 64-bit key and an IV are required for this provider.
    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    'Set the initialization vector.
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    'Create the DES encryptor from this instance.
    Dim desencrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateEncryptor()
    'Create the crypto stream that transforms the file stream by using DES encryption.
    Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, _
                                        desencrypt, _
                                        CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    'Read the file text to the byte array.
    Dim bytearrayinput(fsInput.Length - 1) As Byte
    fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
    'Write out the DES encrypted file.
    cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
    cryptostream.Close()
    System.IO.File.Delete(sInputFilename)
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried issuing `fsInput.Close()` right before `System.IO.File.Delete(sInputFilename)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fsInput.Close()` right before `System.IO.File.Delete(sInputFilename)`

Hope this helps